# stop LocationListener Service

Tags: java, android, service, locationlistener

I'm working on an android applciation, i've created a

```
LocationListener
```

Service where i send my location to the server, all is working but the

```
stopservice()
```

the service keeps running, is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In your service, just call stopSelf() after you are done with the location updates:

```
MyLocationService.this.stopSelf();
```

Also depending if you are using the deprecated `import android.location.LocationListener` or the new `import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener`
you need to onDestory of the serve remove the updates for the location listener or disconnect the API client:

old:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
if (myLocationListener) {
myLocationManager.removeUpdates(myLocationListiener);
}
}
```

new:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
if (myGoogleApiClient) {
myGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
}
}
```

Comment: i'm using the import android.location.LocationListener and i'm calling removeUpdates() and same thing not working

Comment: @Adams, The one you are using is deprecated and Google strongly encourages to use the new gms.location.LocationListener. That being said, the old one should still work. Is your only issue that you cannot stop the service? I am assuming that the LocationListener is in your own service (i.e. MyService extends Service)? If that is the case, once you execute MyService.this.stopSelf(); it will no longer run. Did you try this?

Comment: @Adams Also I am assuming that you start the service by calling startSrevide()? If you are bounding to the service, you need to call unbindService() instead of stopService() or stopSelf

Comment: i'm using the MyService extends Service implements LocationListener, and when i start the service i'm calling bindService() and startService(), and when i stop it i call unbindService() and stopService and in onDestroy i call stopSelf() still not stopping

Comment: @Adams, It seems to me that the line where you are unbinding from the service is never executed. Calling stopSelf() from onDestoroy() is definitely worthless. The onDestroy() is only be called right before the service is stopped. You need to unbind/stop the service in order for the onDestory() to be called. Make sure that the line where you are unbinding the service is actually executed. Put a Log statement right before it, to make sure of that.